# How to Load Firestore Bundles using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As per documentation written in FlutterFire about [Firestore bundles](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#data-bundles), I was unable to create such a thing. It seems documentation lacks something as all I get was error codes: `Permission is denied`

```js
  static const bucket = "felix-3610.appspot.com";
  static const storage = "https://storage.cloud.google.com";
  final Message msg = Get.find();

  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, Object?>>> getEpic() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, Object?>>? snapshot;
    const path = "$storage/$bucket/music/bundles/epic_bundles.txt";
    Reference httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(path);
    try {
      String url = await httpsReference.getDownloadURL();
      final response = await http.get(Uri.https(url));
      Uint8List buffer = Uint8List.fromList(response.body.codeUnits);
      LoadBundleTask task = FirebaseFirestore.instance.loadBundle(buffer);
      await task.stream.last.then((value) async {
        snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("latest-epic").get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      log(e.code); //unauthorized
    }
    return snapshot!;
  }
```

I could not know where I went wrong. Have people tried to code and load Firestore bundles in Flutter? Please, I do need a good documentation of how to do it correctly.

> E/StorageException(24282): StorageException has occurred.
> E/StorageException(24282): User does not have permission to access
> this object. E/StorageException(24282):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
> E/StorageException(24282): {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message":
> "Permission denied."  }} E/StorageException(24282):
> java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message":
> "Permission denied."  }} E/StorageException(24282):   at
> com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/StorageException(24282):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

The way I generated bundle is using Cloud Scheduler, like in this example below:

```js
// @ts-check
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const fs = require("fs");

// This will create it every month
exports.BundleRelax = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 1 * *").retryConfig({
  retryCount: 3,
  maxRetryDuration: "30s",
}).onRun(async (context) => {
  const bundleId = "latest-relax";
  const bundle = firestore.bundle(bundleId);
  const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("Music_Relax").where("status.state", "==", 1).get();

  // Build the bundle
  const bundleBuffer = bundle.add("latest-relax-query", querySnapshot).build();

  // Create tmp local file to upload
  const bundledFilePath = "/tmp/bundle.txt";
  fs.writeFileSync(bundledFilePath, bundleBuffer);

  // Upload bundle file to Storage
  const bucket = "felix-366510.appspot.com";
  const destination = "relax_bundle.txt";
  await admin.storage().bucket(bucket).upload(bundledFilePath, {
    destination,
    public: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: "public, max-age=3110400",
    },
  }).then((value) => {
    return Promise.resolve("success");
  });
});
```

Security Rules for Cloud Storage:

```js
rules_version = '2';
//Read operation: get, list
//Write operation: create, update, delete 
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin();
    }

    match /music {
      allow read: if isIDN();
      allow get, list, create, update: if isPublisher();
    }

    match /server {
      allow read, create, update: if isUser();
    }

    match /publishers {
      allow read: if isUser();
      allow get, list, create, update: if isPublisher();
    }

    match /clients {
      allow read, write: if isFelix();
    }
    //This is for any subcription inside Felix Apps
    //Value 0 is equal to FALSE
    //Value 1 is equal to TRUE
    //This is for all versions
    function isMT() {
        return mtIDN() || mtEN() || mtCHN(); 
    }

    function isMTtrial() {
      return trMT_IDN() || trMT_EN() || trMT_CHN();
    }
  
    //IDN version code 1
    //Trials here
    function trMT_IDN(){
        return isIDN() && (request.auth.token.T11 == 1);
    }

    //Subs here
    function mtIDN(){
        return isIDN() && (request.auth.token.MT1 == 1);
    }

    //EN version code 2
    //Trials here
    function trMT_EN(){
        return isEN() && (request.auth.token.T21 == 1);
    }

    //Subs here
    function mtEN(){
        return isEN() && (request.auth.token.MT2 == 1);
    }

    //CHN version code 3
    //Trials here
    function trMT_CHN(){
        return isCHN() && (request.auth.token.T31 == 1);
    }

    //Subs here
    function mtCHN(){
        return isCHN() && (request.auth.token.MT3 == 1);
    }

    function isFelix(){
      return isIDN() || isEN() || isCHN();
    }

    function isIDN(){
        return isUser() && request.auth.token.IDN == true;
    }

    function isEN(){
        return isUser() && request.auth.token.EN == true;
    }

    function isCHN(){
        return isUser() && request.auth.token.CHN == true;
    }

    function isUser() {
        return (isClient() || isServer());
    }

    function isPublisher(){
      return (isMusician() || isGross() || isNet() || isFree());
    }

    function isMusician(){
        return isUser() && roleNew();
    }
    
    function isNet(){
        return isUser() && roleNet();
    }
    
    function isGross(){
        return isUser() && roleGross();
    }

    function isFree(){
        return isUser() && roleFree();
    }

    function isAdmin(){
        return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.Admin == true;
    }
    
        function isServer(){
        return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.HaD == true;
    }
    
    function isClient(){
        return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.Felix == true;
    }
    
    //This is for roles claim inside HaD App    
    function roleNew(){
        return request.auth.token.role == "Unregistered";
    }
    
    function roleNet(){
        return request.auth.token.role == "Net";
    }
    
        function roleGross(){
        return request.auth.token.role == "Gross";
    }

        function roleFree(){
        return request.auth.token.role == "Free";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to download the bundle or are you having trouble reading the bundle?

Comment: I am having trouble downloading. It said user doesn't have permission in await httpsReference.getData(500000).then((value) => data = value);

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? I imagine if we are getting an error on permissions, it might be your firebase storage permission.

Comment: @AlexanderN now the error is load-bundle-error. I managed to download it with an error. It seems we have to put bundles.txt in public. That way it can be accessed easily from there. I don't know anymore. I have 2 maps inside each document. Maybe that is the problems.

Comment: How'd you generate the bundle? Can you share the data model?

Comment: I added the way I generated bundle up in the post. I run it automatically every once a month.

Comment: I cannot download nor open the bundle.txt. It always said undefined. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: can you post your security rules? If you are unable to download the bundle, it sounds like it may be erlated to your storage security rules.

Comment: @AlexanderN I just added security rules. As I said I have no more problem in there, but now it is related to loading bundle. And it said I had specified wrong argument. I had tested using normal approach to load the data without bundle, and it works. Now what mistakes do I make again? Really confusing. If this is what it is, I will use firestore-cache just to save bandwidth and reads' amount.